# Views in Python3.1?

Tags: python, view, python-3.x

What exactly are views in Python3.1? They seem to behave in a similar manner as that of iterators and they can be materialized into lists too. How are iterators and views different?

Answer (score 13):

From what I can tell, a view is still attached to the object it was created from. Modifications to the original object affect the view.

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) (for dictionary views):

```
>>> dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
>>> keys = dishes.keys()
>>> values = dishes.values()

>>> # iteration
>>> n = 0
>>> for val in values:
...     n += val
>>> print(n)
504

>>> # keys and values are iterated over in the same order
>>> list(keys)
['eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage', 'spam']
>>> list(values)
[2, 1, 1, 500]

>>> # view objects are dynamic and reflect dict changes
>>> del dishes['eggs']
>>> del dishes['sausage']
>>> list(keys)
['spam', 'bacon']

>>> # set operations
>>> keys & {'eggs', 'bacon', 'salad'}
{'bacon'}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you read [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1576-new-iterables-in-python-3-0/). It seems to do the best job of explaining.

As far as I can tell, views seem to be associated more with `dict`s and can be forced into `list`s. You can also make an iterator out of them, through which you could then iterate (in a `for` loop or by calling `next`)

Update: [updated link from wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140219195551/http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1576-new-iterables-in-python-3-0)

Answer (score 2):

> How are iterators and views different?

I'll rephrase the question as "what's the difference between an *iterable* objects and an *iterator*"?

An **iterable** is an object that can be iterated over (e.g. used in a `for` loop).

An **iterator** is an object that can be called with the `next()` function, that is it implements the `.next()` method in Python2 and `.__next__()` in python3. An iterator is often used to wrap an *iterable* and return each item of interest. All iterators are iterable, but the reverse is not necessarily true (all iterables are not iterators).

Views are *iterable* objects, not *iterators*.

Let's look at some code to see the distinction (Python 3):

The ["What's new in Python 3"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) document is very specific about which functions return iterators. `map()`, `filter()`, and `zip()` definitely return an iterator, whereas `dict.items()`, `dict.values()`, `dict.keys()` are said to return a view object. As for `range()`, although the description of what it returns exactly lacks precision, we know it's not an iterator.

Using `map()` to double all numbers in a list

```
m = map(lambda x: x*2, [0,1,2])
hasattr(m, '__next__')
# True
next(m)
# 0
next(m)
# 2
next(m)
# 4
next(m)
# StopIteration ...
```

Using `filter()` to extract all odd numbers

```
f = filter(lambda x: x%2==1, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
hasattr(f, '__next__')
# True
next(f)
# 1
next(f)
# 3
next(f)
# 5
next(f)
# StopIteration ...
```

Trying to use `range()` in the same manner to produce a sequence of number

```
r = range(3) 
hasattr(r, '__next__')
# False
next(r)
# TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

But it's an iterable, so we should be able to wrap it with an iterator

```
it = iter(r)
next(it)
# 0
next(it)
# 1
next(it)
# 2
next(it)
# StopIteration ...
```

`dict.items()` as well as `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` also do not return iterators in Python 3

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
items = d.items()
hasattr(items, '__next__')
# False
it = iter(items)
next(it)
# ('b', 1)
next(it)
# ('c', 2)
next(it)
# ('a', 0)
```

An iterator can only be used in a single `for` loop, whereas an iterable can be used repeatedly in subsequent `for` loops. Each time an iterable is used in this context it implicitely returns a new iterator (from its `__iter__()` method). The following custom class demonstrates this by outputting the memory `id` of both the list object and the returning iterator object:

```
class mylist(list):
    def __iter__(self, *a, **kw):
        print('id of iterable is still:', id(self))
        rv = super().__iter__(*a, **kw)
        print('id of iterator is now:', id(rv))
        return rv 

l = mylist('abc')
```

A `for` loop can use the iterable object and will implicitly get an iterator

```
for c in l:
    print(c)
# id of iterable is still: 139696242511768
# id of iterator is now: 139696242308880
# a
# b
# c
```

A subsequent `for` loop can use the same iterable object, but will get another iterator

```
for c in l:
    print(c)
# id of iterable is still: 139696242511768
# id of iterator is now: 139696242445616
# a
# b
# c
```

We can also obtain an iterator explicitly

```
it = iter(l)
# id of iterable is still: 139696242511768
# id of iterator is now: 139696242463688
```

but it can then only be used once

```
for c in it:
    print(c)
# a
# b
# c
for c in it:
    print(c)
for c in it:
    print(c)
```