# Difference between a view and assignment

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I can understand the difference between an assignment, shallow and deep copy. But I am still unclear what is the difference between a view(`c=a`) and an assignment(`c=a.view()`). Both reflect changes and seem the same. Please give **examples** if possible.

I am referring to the views here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html . I am unsure these views behave similarly to the dict views(https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Comment: Can you give the context for these terms?  A view is generally a database, not a python, term.  However there are *view objects* in python.

Comment: @zondo can you provide a python example to better understand.

Comment: These terms require more context. It's hard to imagine any context in which they would be comparable, though; a view is a thing, while assignment is an action.

Comment: @cdarke referring to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784169/views-in-python3-1

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia "... in scipy" would be a really relevant thing to include in your question.

Comment: @user2357112 please consider view as creating a view.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: The second example isn't NumPy or SciPy at all, though; the second example is about dict views.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Well, you've managed to confuse things even more. `c=a` is an assignment, while `c=a.view()` creates a view and assigns it to a variable. They're pretty much the opposite of what you're saying.

Comment: @user2357112 but you have to assign a view to name isn't?  What does a view mean without name.

Comment: Please check the edit now.

Comment: An assignment is an action, a view is an object.  You could say that an assignment names a view (or any other object).

Comment: @user2357112 if the OP actually tried doing anything with a dictionary view they would see the difference almost immediately.  for one `d['a']` will return the value associated with the key `'a'` where as `d.keys()["a"]` or `d.items()['a']` or `d.values()['a']` are all invalid.

Comment: @user2357112 my question is for scipy views. I don't know if they are similar to the dict views. In scipy, a view is the same type of object unlike in the example you mentioned an assignment is dictionary and view is a list.

Answer (score 5):

A array object in NumPy is a ndarray struct with a `data` pointer that point to the raw values in the array.

- `b = a`: Just give the array another name.
- `c = a.view()`: Create a view of array `a` means create a new ndarray struct that point to the same raw values.

Here is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = a
c = a.view()

print(id(a), id(b), id(c))
print(a.ctypes.data, b.ctypes.data, c.ctypes.data)
```

output:

```
140328594430752 140328594430752 140328594428432
40268384 40268384 40268384
```

- `a` and `b` have the same `id` means they are the same object.
- all have the same `data` pointer means they share the same raw data.

Here is what created in the memory:

[image]

Here is the document about ndarray struct:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject

Comment: Another handy way to get information about the data buffer  is `a.__array_interface__` (a dictionary that includes the `data` pointer).  `b=a[:]` and similar slicing also creates a view.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer. I know what an object is. Can you provide information about what a data pointer is.

Comment: I added a link to the numpy document, the data pointer is the data field in `PyArrayObject`.

Comment: You wrote `all have the same data pointer ` But doesn't c have a different one.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia the same data pointer means the pointers point to the same address.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary `dictview` has nothing to do with `numpy` array views.  It's just a cover term for the object that  `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` create in Python3.  They are are more like generators, that require a `list(...)` wrapper.  Trying to understand those while working with arrays will just confuse you.

With `numpy` arrays, you need to understand the distinction between copies and views.  That in turn requires a basic understanding of what an array object is, and how it stores its data.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#copies-and-views

```
b = a
```

`b` is another name for `a`.  Both names point to the same array object

```
b = a[:]
b = a.view()
b = a[:4]
b = a.reshape(1,-1)
b = np.array(a,copy=False)  # but read the np.array docs
```

`b` is a new array object, but it shares the underlying data buffer with `a`.  Changes to values in `b` will be seen in `a`.  `b` may have different shape.

```
b = a.copy()
b = a.astype(int)
b = np.array(a, copy=True)
b = a[[1,2,3]]
```

`b` is a new array, and has a copy of the `a` data buffer.  Changes to `b` are independent of changes in `a`.